# How to manage multiple deployments of a JavaScript Web App

Tags: javascript, deployment, configuration, web-deployment, multiple-instances

I have a JavaScript web application that we are offering to customers using a SaaS model.  Right now, the application consists of several HTML files, JavaScript files, CSS files, and image files as well as a single proxy page (ashx file) with a config file.  We have deployed the app on GoDaddy's shared hosting service.

We currently deploy an exact copy of the entire app folder structure for each customer and I am quickly realizing that this is a nightmare in terms of maintenance when I need to provide an update or bug fix.  I have to make the change to every instance of the app for every customer.

Is there a better way to handle this?  I've heard of using a single code base with multiple config files for dynamic apps built on server-side technologies like ASP.Net or PHP, but I have no clue how I can do this with JavaScript, especially since the HTML pages need to be slightly different for each customer.

Comment: Can you not package up an installer that only updates the core engine files? i.e. ignore the views, update the business code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  How would I use an installer for Javascript?

Comment: Have an installer that copies the "core" files to where they need to go

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it still means that I have many copies of the same file (1 for each customer deployment).  Is it possible to deploy in a way that I do not need a copy of each file for each deployment and instead I just have a single file that all instances use?